# :value is not set on hidden input field using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set values for a input field using vue.js

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" :value="response.name">
```

Code that fetch api:

```
fetch: function(){
    axios.post("/api/get-details", { id: 54 })
    .then(response => {
        this.details = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {

    });
},
```

The input only shows the name and type and the value is not showing anything in the sourcecode.

My editor is saying: "Attribute :value is not allowed here"

Any ideas why this is not giving me any values?

Comment: Is `response` a prop or v-model

Comment: thats a response from api, data: { response: []}

Comment: When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data option, Vue will walk through all of its properties but int your case, those properties are being formed dynamically and that's why it isn't reactive. You can use another object and shallow copy response to that & then use that object reference in you hidden input

Comment: how would this look in the script?

Comment: Please post your data and api callback.

Comment: Added callback, think its the same as the one u pasted?

Comment: You're assigning response to "details" in your :value you should access it as "details.name"

Answer (score 0):

These are the 2 most common issues when an element is no `reactive`.

1. You must make sure to declare `response` as `null` or `undefined`.  Otherwise `Vue` will not track the item.

```
data: ()=>({response:null})
```

2. Make sure to use `lambda` and not `function` so `this` references your component in your API callback.

```
created() {
  myApi.getResponse(response=>{
    this.response = response
  })
}
```